# How to get parent with only the first child in using eloquent orm?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, parent-child

I'm trying to get the active(i.e active = 1) albums from my album table which has at least 1 active image with the first active image in descending order of date created. i.e the each album's image must be the last active image to be created.

My Album model is:

```
class Album extends Model {
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Images','album_id');
    }

    public function scopeActive($query){
        return $query->where('is_active', 1);
    }
}
```

My Images Model is:

```
class Images extends Model {

    public function scopeActive($query){
        return $query->where('is_active', 1);
    }

    public function album(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Album', 'album_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

So far I've come up with the following:

```
$albums = Album::with(['images' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            $query->first();
        }])
        ->whereHas('images', function ($query) {
            $query->active();
        })
        ->active()
        ->get();
```

The above result would give me the following array with image for only one album:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Test Gallery
        [slug] => test-gallery
        [description] => this is test gallery
        [cover_image] => 
        [is_active] => 1
        [created_by] => 2
        [updated_by] => 2
        [deleted_at] => 
        [images] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => My Gallery 2
        [slug] => my-gallery-2
        [description] => Hello, this is my second gallery.
        [cover_image] => 
        [is_active] => 1
        [created_by] => 2
        [updated_by] => 
        [deleted_at] => 
        [images] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 9
                        [album_id] => 3
                        [image] => gallery_xfWjm0JuzZ.jpg
                        [description] => 
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [created_by] => 2
                        [updated_by] => 
                        [deleted_at] => 
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Can anyone help me to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What result do you get with your current query?

Comment: Please see the question again, I've added the array result I got from my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like:

```
class Album extends Model
{
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->images()
            ->active()
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take(1)
            ->first();
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Images','album_id');
    }

    public function scopeActive($query){
        return $query->where('is_active', 1);
    }
}

$albums = Album::active()->whereHas('images', function ($query) {
    $query->active();
})->get();

foreach ($albums as $album) {
    var_dump($album->image());
}
```

Comment: This will work, but this will execute `n + 1` queries. Which should be avoided.

Comment: Yep, I noticed it. Any idea how it can be avoided in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `whereHas` method:

```
$albums = Album::whereHas('images', function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
})->get();
```

It'll retrieve all albums that have at least one active image

Comment: but this wouldn't retrieve first images for all the albums, would it?